# 特定の文字列が含まれている行だけを抽出する方法を伺いたいです

Tags: python, python3

複数のコラムをもつファイルを読み込んで、1つのコラムに特定の文字列が含まれている場合にその行を行ごと取り出す方法についてです。具体的には以下のような入力ファイルで、Mrを含む行のみを抽出する方法を知りたいです。

```
  name    age
1 Mr.A    30
2 Miss.B  20
3 Mr.C    25
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: お使いの Python は 2.x ですか？3.xですか？また，入力は標準入力ですか？それともファイルから読み込みたいですか？

Comment: @wtsnjp ３です。KaggleのTitanicに挑戦しているのですが、csvを読み込んで操作しています。

Answer (score 1):

for 文とともに `open()` 関数でファイルを読み込むことで，行ごとのイテレーション処理が行なえます．Python では「文字列 A が文字列 B に含まれるか否か」は `A in B` で判定できるので，例えば以下のようにすれば `Mr.` という文字列を含む行だけが出力されます．

```
for l in open('input.txt'):
    if "Mr." in l:
        print(l, end='')
```

Comment: 出力された文字列をDataFrameの形にすることは可能ですか？また、質問の仕方が悪かったのですが、データにはMrsの文字列も入っており、Mrのみで抽出をしたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: pandas を import して(`import pandas as pd`)、データを読み込んで(`df = pd.read_table('tbl.dat')`)、目的の行を抽出する(`df[df.name.str.contains('Mr')]`) など。

Comment: `Mr.` とピリオド (`.`) まで含めた文字列で判定しているので `Mrs.` の行は取らないと思います．name 以外のカラムにも `Mr.` という文字列が現れる可能性がある場合はもう少し複雑で，正規表現の利用なども検討する必要があります．

Comment: `Mr.` だけなら `df[df.name.str.contains('Mr\.')]` となります。

Answer (score 1):

Kaggleの乗客名簿のデータだとすると、'Mr'を含む行を抽出するのではなくて、列`name`に敬称の'Mr.'が含まれるものを抽出するという問題ではないでしょうか。'Mr.'の前は通常空白になるので、以下のようにして調べてみて、もし両方あれば`concat`するのが一番いいのではないでしょうか。

```
df[df['name'].str.startswith('Mr.')]
df[df['name'].str.contains(' Mr.')]
```

このケースでは、以下でも問題はありませんが、英単語の場合はスペースで区切られているので間違って拾うのを避けるためにスペースを最初に入れて検束するのが有効な場合が多いと思います。

```
df[df['name'].str.contains('Mr.')]
```

また、敬称を予測モデルに使いたいのであれば、`split`を使って分解してみたらどうでしょうか。（一般的には、`Mr.`の場合、前後にスペースがくるので正規表現を使わなくても単に`split()`でもスペースで分解してくれるので問題ないかも）

```
df['name'].str.split(r'[\s\.]', expand=True)
```